# possible combinations of strings in an array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, python-3.4, python-itertools

`arr=['one','two','three']`

Result must be like this:
`onetwo,twothree,onethree`

> itertools.permutations will not work in this situation.

we can do this by simply adding for loops and appending them ,that works for small arrays but takes time for big arrays.

I was wondering is there any way `(like itertools.permutations)`this can be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps what you wanted was the `itertools.combinations`?

```
>>> [''.join(comb) for comb in (itertools.combinations(arr, 2))]
['onetwo', 'onethree', 'twothree']
```

Comment: Is there any way applying this to two different arrays.?I mean arr1=['name1','name2'];arr2=['name3','name4'].output should be `name1name3,name1name4,name2name3,name3name4`

Answer (score 1):

> for two lists
>
> - create a list with equal length compare with other list
> - zip new list with other list
> - put all sublist together
> - join list

```
from itertools import permutations

arr1=['name1','name2']
arr2=['name3','name4']

set( map(lambda x: ''.join(x),reduce( lambda x,y:x+y, [  zip(i,arr1) for i in permutations(arr2,len(arr1)) ] ) ) )

output:

set(['name3name1', 'name3name2', 'name4name1', 'name4name2'])
```